# Select DOM-element of HTML-control and forward its DOM-path to Actionscript method

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, flexbuilder

Suppose, that I need to have a **HTML control** inside my Flex/AIR app.

The user should be able to **click somewhere into the currently rendered HTML-page** and the flex app should know, which **DOM element the user clicked**.

Ideally, the app would be able to retrieve the **DOM path** of the selected element. Posting back the **innermost surrounding DIV-element** to some Flex/AIR method would be fine too.

**Q:** Does flex provide something in the framework for this task? Or do you know of sample code?

Comment: Why not use ExternalInterface?

Comment: @The_asMan please 10 more words of explanation!

Comment: ExternalInterface is an AS3 class that allows you to call JavaScript functions directly from your flash app. It can also add callback functions so that JavaScript can call AS3 functions in your app.

Comment: go here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6 and look at the sample at the bottom. I prefer to keep JS separate from AS3 instead of AS3 doing the JS calls directly. It tends to be more developer friendly and easier to maintain.

Comment: @The_asMan Yes, I'd prefer that too. What I'm going to do is pick elements of a HTML-page. At the next start the application should grab the current DOM-content based on the path defined by the previously picked elements. Kind of scraping.

Comment: @The_asMan: Because it's AIR. The HTML resides within the AIR runtime as opposed to being *external* to the Flash Player. There's no point in using it, if you can directly access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a callback to the `window` property of the `HTMLLoader` within the `HTML` element.  A quick example (using jQuery for expediency):

HTML page here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/w23Xx/1/show/     (Source [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w23Xx/1/))

Flex code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function html1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // Add the click callback
                html.htmlLoader.window.flexClickCallback = function(element:Object):void
                {
                    trace("Element ID:", element.id);
                };
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:HTML id="html" location="http://fiddle.jshell.net/w23Xx/1/show/" left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10" creationComplete="html1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" />

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

I believe you can add listeners directly, but this shows how you access the page's `window`.

**Edit:**

Mike Chambers posted an [example](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2007/11/09/using-the-htmlcontrol-in-adobe-air-to-parse-html-as-a-data-source/) of doing DOM manipulation directly within the AS of an AIR app.

Comment: Thx! Now it's time to add some logic to recursive walk to all DOM elements and attach a handler to each element in search. Any hints how to inject the JS Code into the web page? In case it is not mine?

Comment: @StefanPantke: See example added in edit above for more DOM manipulation guidelines.

Comment: @N Rohler Please forgive, but this solution is more restrictive than my question asked for. I need to load SOME/ANY webpage and then resolve the clicked element ID or XPath. Somehow injecting JS dynamically is denied by Actionscript.